# Python urllib2.open Connection reset by peer error

Tags: python, connection, screen-scraping, reset

I'm trying to scrape a page using python

The problem is, I keep getting Errno54 Connection reset by peer.

The error comes when I run this code -

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10161&langId=-1&programId=562&termId=100020629&divisionDisplayName=Stanford&departmentDisplayName=ILAC&courseDisplayName=126&sectionDisplayName=01&demoKey=d&purpose=browse")
```

this happens for all the urls on this pag- what is the issue?

Comment: Can you open the link on your browser? If not, then it is not correct to expect the Python command to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$> telnet www.bkstr.com 80
Trying 64.37.224.85...
Connected to www.bkstr.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10161&langId=-1&programId=562&termId=100020629&divisionDisplayName=Stanford&departmentDisplayName=ILAC&courseDisplayName=126&sectionDisplayName=01&demoKey=d&purpose=browse HTTP/1.0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

You're not going to have any joy fetching that URL from python, or anywhere else. If it works in your browser then there must be something else going on, like cookies or authentication or some such. Or, possibly, the server's broken or they've changed their configuration.

Try opening it in a browser that you've never accessed that site in before to check. Then log in and try it again.

Edit: It was cookies after all:

```
import cookielib, urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#Need to set a cookie
opener.open("http://www.bkstr.com/")
#Now open the page we want
data = opener.open("http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10161&langId=-1&programId=562&termId=100020629&divisionDisplayName=Stanford&departmentDisplayName=ILAC&courseDisplayName=126&sectionDisplayName=01&demoKey=d&purpose=browse").read()
```

The output looks ok, but you'll have to check that it does what you want :)

Comment: Not by a simply GET request, it seems. What are you trying to find on the website? (I'll have a look to see if there's another way for you).

Comment: for some reason, I can't access the page through safari

Comment: well I'm trying to get the class name and textbooks for each class- search Stanford Bookstore, then  go to textbooks&course materials, I want to find the information for all classes listed under Stanford (in one of their drop down boxes)

Comment: sorry- the above wasn't very clear- with the code that I've posted, I'm trying to get the class name and textbook name (with author) on the page of the pasted url

Comment: wait- so what was the problem?

Comment: When you access the first page ("http://www.bkstr.com/") it sets a cookie (presumably with tracking information, but you can check by interrogating the cookie). It seems to break (as in explode) if you access subsequent pages without having that cookie in place. So my code accesses the first page and gets the cookie, then accesses the second page with the cookie in place.

Comment: If it works for you then you might like to close your other question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar error just recently. The connection was dropping out and being reset. I tried cookiejars, extended delays and different headers/useragents, but nothing worked. In the end the fix was simple. I went from urllib2 to requests. The old;

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
buf = opener.open(url).read()
```

The new;

```
import requests
buf = requests.get(url).text
```

After that everything worked perfectly.